# How do you determine the client side requests necessary for logins & http-requests all automatically?

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, client-server, httprequest

*edit:  Its leaning into HttpListener at this point.. It might also have to be done via Sockets + webclient or all sockets*  You have to make a GET request to retrieve the request headers, that's about all... Sockets also can allow the server to PUSH things to the clients without having needed a request, which can't be done via webclients*

What i'm looking to do is type in a url to a website login server: college campus, email, forums, other things you'd need daily and create a working login for them.  Since each server can vary, request types change:  (ie): //castRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
              //castRequest.ContentType = *"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"*;

how would these necessary changes be found from a C# client rather than manually laboring through packets and other harsh methods?

**Here we go...**
 - ok you open a site
 - no problem
 - you grab some login tags from the html, easy enough..
 - now where i'm at: where you try to login
 - sending a user/pw isn't just a post of those two things
 - nor is just getting to the page sometimes either
 - there are http credentials, network credentials, and security credentials + USER/PW 
credentials

the html user/pw inputs are easy enough to parse out: input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="15" value="">, back to the question of ---> **how would you connect and determine all requests that the server wants?**

How would i go about analyzing and turning these requests on/off per-request & also how would i grab the data from the network: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?  I'm also finding that this doesn't always return the same *#* of cookies that i'll get via certain browsers or other systems.  WHY???

Code snippet that will be necessary://BEGIN

usually these sites have cookies enabled, so you use a cookie enabled WebClient:

```
namespace watcher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
//throw in a function create a cookie container:
void startRequest(){
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HTTP http = new HTTP(cookieJar);
}
        public class HTTP : WebClient
        {
            public HTTP()
            : this(new CookieContainer())
            { }

            public HTTP(CookieContainer c)
            {
                CookieContainer = c;
            }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (castRequest != null)
            {
                castRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
                //castRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                //castRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }
                return request;
            }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a combination of the Firefox add-ons Greasemonkey and Firebug. You can't really programmatically determine what the servers expect. They are written by humans and each will have had problems solved using creativity. You will have to establish, for each individually what the server expects, by hand. Even then it won't be easy, (or in some cases, I imagine, even possible.) The servers you're trying to log into may react differently to different clients, for all kinds of reasons which one could only guess at. (Which is why you'd be experiencing the issue with cookies). You don't need to labour through packets, but you do need to manually look at what requests are being sent and received, the content of those, and the meaning of the data. To get further help, you'll need to look at each one individually and ask specific questions.

Comment: +1. Fiddler is another option to look at requests... Side note: since OP tries to sign in as self it should be always possible for regular web authentication (also I agree that something like smart cards or two-factor-authorization would not be possible to completely automate).

Comment: You're sort of way wrong on all levels, It's a protocol, use it.  I'm looking into HttpListener at this point

Comment: I see what you're saying now. In which case what you want is something which will interpret and run the javascript, flash and/or other stuff that determines what's sent back to the server. You'd be better off using something which just fills out the forms in a regular browser, like greasemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Its looking like HttpListener at this point.. It might also have to be done via Sockets + webclient or all sockets*  You have to make a GET request to retrieve the request headers, that's about all... Sockets also can allow the server to PUSH things to the clients without having needed a request, which can't be done via webclients*

It's HTTP Protocol, without a client/server handshake none of the internet would work.  You're not required to have upfront info other than an address.  The servers' job is to work for you, not the other way around.